# Why is the pronunciation of 'ch' different in chamber and chameleon?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Sometimes ch is pronounced as /k/, as in chorus/chameleon. Sometimes as /tʃ/, as in chamber/chalk.

Why is it so?

Comment: English pronunciation is not dependent on spelling, and neither is its spelling dependent on pronunciation, so *why* almost always relates to historical factors such as etymology, not "rules" of spelling or pronunciation that many attempt to devise. See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74951/why-is-go-spelled-with-the-same-vowel-as-do-and-to-since-it-is-pronounced/74990 http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8883/why-does-english-spelling-use-silent-letters

Comment: For a more comprehensive discussion of English spelling and pronunciation quirks, see [Hou tu pranownse Inglish](http://www.zompist.com/spell.html). It misses a few subtleties (like the _ch_ in _machine_), but overall it's a nice summary of English pronunciation rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While *chamber* comes from the French *chambre* and has an English approximation of the French, *chameleon* comes from Greek and the first sound is an English approximation of the Greek letter χ.

Another curiosity that the French *chambre* comes from the Latin *camera*, and the English for the photographic equipment (originally *camera obscura*) came more directly from Latin.  *Shirt* and *skirt* are other examples where the English pronunciation depends on the language route taken.

There is often no logic: the English *church* and Scots *kirk* are essentially the same word with different pronunciations evolving over time, and both changed the spelling to be more phonetic.